# Passar valor de sessão php para Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Preciso pegar uma valor de uma sessão do php que está em uma página onde tenho um formulário de contato e passar por Ajax para uma outra página, nessa página faço a verificação se o valores são iguais ou não, mas não estou conseguindo realizar.

O meu código captcha cria a sessão vejam:

```
<?php

session_start();

$codigoCaptcha = substr(md5( time()) ,0,9); 
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $codigoCaptcha;  

$imagemCaptcha = imagecreatefrompng("fundocaptch.png");
$fonteCaptcha = imageloadfont("anonymous.gdf");
$corCaptcha = imagecolorallocate($imagemCaptcha,127,82,53);

imagestring($imagemCaptcha,$fonteCaptcha,15,5,$codigoCaptcha,$corCaptcha);

header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($imagemCaptcha);
imagedestroy($imagemCaptcha);

?>
```

Tentei passar a variável de sessão assim:

```
    <script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").on("click", function(event){
        var nome      = $("#nome").val();
        var email     = $("#email").val();
        var uf        = $("#uf").val();
        var municipio = $("#municipio").val();
        var telefone  = $("#telefone").val();
        var grupo     = $("#grupo").val();
        var assunto   = $("#assunto").val();
        var mensagem  = $("#mensagem").val();   
        var captcha   = $("#captcha").val();
        var captcha_sessao = $("#SESSION['captcha']").val();    

        alert(captcha_sessao);

        var emailFilter = /^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
        var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\/\"\[\]]/;

        if((emailFilter.test(email))||email.match(illegalChars)){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "processo.php",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function(){
                    $(".processo").html('Gravando contato...');
                },
                data: {'nome':nome,
                       'email':email,
                       'uf':uf,
                       'municipio':municipio,
                       'telefone':telefone,
                       'grupo':grupo,
                       'assunto':assunto,
                       'mensagem':mensagem,
                       'captcha':captcha,
                       'captcha_sessao':captcha_sessao},
                success: function(json){
                    if(json.tipo == "0"){ // erro
                        $(".processo").html("<span class='erro'>"+json.msg+"</span>");
                    }else{ // sucesso
                        $(".processo").html("<span class='sucesso'>"+json.msg+"</span>");
                        cleanFields();
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            $(".processo").html("<p style='color:#f25824'>Por favor, informe um e-mail válido.</p>");
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });

}); 

</script>
```

O valor dessa variável que é o campo informado com o captcha gerado é enviado para a página processo.php:

```
var captcha   = $("#captcha").val();
```

Não sei exatamente como proceder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi da pergunta e do código, você está querendo fazer uma verificação CAPTCHA. Ao criar uma sessão server side (com o PHP), normalmente um cookie no lado do cliente é criado para guardar o ID daquela sessão.

Então: O seu script salva o captcha na sessão:

```
$_SESSION['captcha'] = $codigoCaptcha;
```

Tudo que você precisa fazer é enviar a requisição do formulário via AJAX, com o valor do campo que o usuário digitou:

```
var captcha   = $("#captcha").val();
```

Ou seja, você não precisa passar outras informações relativas a sessões ou CAPTCHA. O que acontece agora é o seguinte: No lado do servidor, com PHP, você acessa a sessão novamente, e verifica se o valor salvo pelo script gerador do CAPTCHA é o mesmo que o usuário digitou no campo. Exemplo:

*processo.php*

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['captcha'])
    die('O captcha digitado é inválido');
```

A sessão e seus valores são criadas pelo PHP, e ficam salvas no servidor.
Sugiro uma olhada na documentação sobre sessões [aqui](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/intro.session.php) e [aqui](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/aprendendo-a-usar-sessoes-no-php/).

Comment: Olá @Calebe Oliveira, obrigado pelas dicas, resolvi meu problema, dei uma limpada no histórico e funcionou.